# SharePoint 2016 remote blob store error with SQL Server 2014 Standard Edition

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, rbs

We were working on blob storage configuration but getting an error "**Blob store type cannot be used in this edition of SQL Server. RBS upgrade has not been performed. Upgrade the server to Enterprise or Developer Edition**"

So just want to make sure RBS is possible or not with SQL Standard Edition. As I could not find any clear instruction anywhere.

I found that it needs Enterprise like 
"**To run RBS on a remote server, you must be running SQL Server 2008 R2, SQL Server 2012, or SQL Server 2014 Enterprise on the server that is running SQL Server where the metadata is stored in the database.**"

Then what it means by

"**The FILESTREAM provider that is recommended for upgrading from stand-alone installations of Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 that have content databases that are over 4 gigabytes (GB) to SharePoint 2013 associates data locally with the current content database, and does not require SQL Server Enterprise.**"

We use FILESTREAM.

Are we missing anything or we just need SQL Enterprise?

Your help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure RBS in SharePoint with a SQL Server Standard Edition. FileStream-Provider is included there. But it contains a lot of limitations. You might have one of that limitations in your configuration and so you get your mentioned error.

Most times i see customers, which want to move their BLOBs to a network-device. This is not supported with FILESTREAM and Standard-Edition. You have to use a disk that is listed in Windows Diskmanagement (Local Disk, iSCSI Disk, FibreChannel Disk).

[This PDF](https://avepointcdn.azureedge.net/pdfs/en/Storage_Management_vs_RBS_FILESTREAM_Provider.pdf) from AvePoint is a very good overview of the FILESTREAM-Limitations.

Comment: Thanks MHeld for confirmation that we can configure RBS in SharePoint with a SQL Server Standard Edition. 

Yes We use disk that is listed in windows disk management, local drive.